# A really really shy question about language

Tags: language-barrier, italian-citizens, english-language, bern

In four months I'll set off for my first solo travel, at the age of 18. I'll stay in Bern for about 4 days, and of course I'm not enough wealthy for booking in a B&B or a hotel. My only option is choosing a hostel bUT...even if I can speak English it makes me really nervous. I'm Italian, so English is not my first languange, and I don't want to show up,,,
Do you have some advice for me?

Comment: This question is not really specific enough to work well here. Are you expecting answers like take a friend, learn French, take a guidebook, rely on Google translate, or what? SE is very good at giving answers if you can give us a specific question, but just asking for advice is too broad.

Comment: Italian is an official language of Switzerland. That plus English should get you quite far.

Comment: Go on enjoy your trip don’t worry about the language barrier. It always works out just fine for short trips

Comment: Just go, you will find that many more people have little English, likely less than you, and still manage. And you will find that when you have to speak English, you can.

Comment: Bern is located in german canton, so their English will be similar to yours.